# Simple proof that density operator has only pure point spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Is there any simple proof that self-adjoint, nonnegative and trace one operators have only point spectrum? Namely, we want to show that if a bounded operator $\rho$ on $\mathcal{H}$ is such that
$$
\rho=\rho^\dagger,
$$
$$
(v,\rho v)\geq0, \text{for any } v\in\mathcal{H},
$$
$$
{\rm Tr}(\rho)=1,
$$
the it can be decomposed as $\rho=\sum_k\rho_k P_k$ where $\rho_k$ are the eigenvalues of $\rho$ and $P_k$ the projectors onto the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors associated to $\rho_k$.

Comment: I read that every trace class operator is Hilbert Schmidt and as such, compact. This is a sufficient argument.

Comment: @Gribouillis, Thanks, this is true, but I find not to be very simple to prove it. Neither it is simple to show that compact operators only have point spectrum. This is very general, I'm looking for something more "straightforward" to this case, in case there may exist...